# Espacio de no separación en símbolos concretos con regla CSS

Tags: css, css3

Quisiera saber si CSS permite crear alguna regla que, por ejemplo, cuando haya *? ! :* no las separe de la palabra inmediatamente anterior o posterior dejando el correspondiente espacio blanco entre ellas si la palabra debe pasar a otra línea.

---

Ejemplo:

```
Estoy jugando con ¡ Pepito !
```

Si la frase no entra en una línea con ese espacio de no separación queda

```
Estoy jugando con
¡ Pepito !
```

---

Ese espacio de no separación lo pongo yo a mano. Lo que quiero saber es si existe la opción con CSS de que cuando vea los ¡ ! ya ponga esos espacios de separación automáticamente.

La opción de usar javascript, cualquier otro código de programación o depender de instrucciones concretas de navegador queda descartado. Debe ser exclusivamente en CSS.

Gracias.

Comment: A ver si entiendo: si tienes algo como `pepito ! juanito`, buscas una regla CSS que lo muestre `pepito! juanito` ?

Comment: @Alfabravo tienes razón, no está muy claro. He editado la pregunta. Espero que ahora me haya explicado mejor :)

Comment: Se veia mal, he editado la pregunta para forzar la visualización que has puesto, pero sigo sin ver claro que quieres. ¿Qué es un espacio de no separación para ti? ¿un `&nlbr;`?

Comment: Tal vez cuando amanezca el día haya mejores respuestas pero, hasta donde me da el CSS, esto no es posible a menos que rodees cada carácter `!` con una etiqueta que te permita identificarlo en tu hoja de estilos

Comment: @Alfabravo nah, aqui esta amaneciendo el dia y no tengo mejores respuestas :-)

Comment: Bueno, he encontrado algo, pero implica encerrar el texto a bajar con un `<span>` y una clase... aqui dejo un ejemplo por si te sirve: https://jsfiddle.net/0fkh9Ldj/

Comment: @masterguru Me refiero al uso de &nbsp; que evita que se separen dos palabras si hay un salto de línea. Gracias por poner mejor el ejemplo. Todavía estoy algo verde con el funcionamiento de esta plataforma.
Respecto al uso de un span, es una opción pero en ese caso me resulta más sencillo poner directamente el $nbsp;
Siguiendo tu ejemplo si pongo el siguiente código funciona igualmente: <p>Estoy jugando con ¡&nbsp;Pepito&nbsp;!</p>

Comment: Si, claro, me confundi de tag, era `&nbsp;` tal como dices.  Y si, es más logigo que sigas poniendo eso que no todo el `<span>` pero como lo querias por CSS pues eso podria ser una posible solución :-)